# Capture Url Image JavaFX

Tags: image, url, webview, javafx

I have a webview where I view images that comes from a research (with Custom search API),  by clicking on one of them ( once or twice is indifferent , I need to understand the concept ) I should be able to capture his Url and hten close the webview . At the moment the Url images are static and managed with an ArrayList, because I do the research in another class, the next and last step will be integrate the webview inside the Jframe, but this will be an other question. So, How can I get that Url?

Here the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class WebViewSample extends Application {
    private Scene scene;
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create the scene
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(),750,500, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        //scene.getStylesheets().add("webviewsample/BrowserToolbar.css"); 

        stage.show();

//        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
//            @Override
//            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
//                System.out.println("mouse click detected! " + mouseEvent.getSource());
//            }
//        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
class Browser extends Region {

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {
        //apply the styles
        getStyleClass().add("browser");
        // load the web page
        int i=0;
        //webEngine.load("https://www.google.it/earth/images/products_mobile.png");

        String first ="<html> <body>";
        String fin ="</body>  </html>";
        String complete = "";


        ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add("http://www.google.it/events/images/speakers_global/marco_polillo.jpg");
        test.add("https://www.google.it/earth/images/products_mobile.png");



        complete = complete.concat(first);
        for(int j = 0; j< test.size(); j++)
        {

            complete = complete.concat("<img src=");
            complete = complete.concat(test.get(j));
            complete = complete.concat(" style= padding:10px; margin:20px; display:inline-block; margin: 0px 12px 12px 0px; overflow: ; position: relative; vertical-align: top; z-index: 5; height:200px width:auto border:6px solid red>");



        }


        complete = complete.concat(fin);

        browser.getEngine().loadContent(complete);


        //add the web view to the scene
        getChildren().add(browser);


    }
    private Node createSpacer() {
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return spacer;
    }

    @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h,0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return 750;
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return 500;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

The clicking on the images happens in the WebPage itself and you do not get any event of the clicking in the JavaFX part, so you could handle it. What you can do is have a JavaScript function which calls a method in your Java code, when a image is clicked. In JavaScript you have full access to the document and can figure out which image was clicked on.

Here is the part that you need to establish the bridge:

```
public class Bridge{
    WebEngine engine;    // add a new field

    public Bridge(WebEngine engine){
        this.engine = engine;
    }
    public void clickedOnImage(String imageUrl) {
        // TODO fill in your logic
    }

}

// In your Browser class Constructor
JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) engine.executeScript("window");
jsobj.setMember("java", new Bridge(engine));   // pass it here
```

In your JavaScript code you can then call this Java method:

```
var imgSrc = ...
java.clickedOnImage(imgSrc);
```

See

- http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/1500__JavaFX_WebEngine.htm
- http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html